# different locale for specific bundle symfony

Tags: symfony, bundle, locale

I need to set default locale for specific bundle

For example I have two bundles **AppBundle** and **AdminBundle**

in **AppBundle** locale is setted with routes

**but** **AdminBundle** should be always only *'en'* without setting in the router

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have got it!

Just need to add defaults param to the routing.yml

In my case it looks like this

```
admin:
    resource: "@AdminBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /admin
    defaults: { _locale: en } # default locale for all routes /admin/..
```